# How to convert a string into dictionary, with string as key and data type as value in dict

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dictionary

I have a string dictionary as user input in Python console.

The string format looks like `"{"Column A": str, "Column B": str}"`. Eventually, I want to convert this string to dict format like `{"Column A": str, "Column B": str}` so that I could use it in Pandas read_csv() converters.

However, I was unable to use json.loads() to convert, since the values are not string, but data types. I'm wondering if there's any good way to convert this string into dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Answered myself. I was able to use the eval() method to resolve this issue.

```
input_string = '{"Column A": str, "Column B": str}'

dict = eval(input_string)

print(dict)
```

The output is `{'Column A': <class 'str'>, 'Column B': <class 'str'>}`. No error.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you have a string representation of a dictionary where the values are not string literals but actual data types. In this case, you can use the `ast.literal_eval()` function from the `ast` module in Python to safely evaluate the string as a Python expression. Here's an example of how you can use it to convert your string to a dictionary:

```py
import ast

input_string = '{"Column A": str, "Column B": str}'

# Safely evaluate the string as a Python expression
dictionary = ast.literal_eval(input_string)

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'Column A': <class 'str'>, 'Column B': <class 'str'>}
```

Now you have a dictionary with the correct data types. You can pass this dictionary to the `converters` parameter of the `read_csv()` function in pandas to define custom converters for specific columns.

Keep in mind that `ast.literal_eval()` evaluates the string as a Python expression, so make sure the input string is trusted and doesn't contain any malicious code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used your code snippet in an online editor but it returned an error `ValueError: malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x12dfe7e20>`. Same thing happened in my IDE too. Any fix for this error?

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.